# Conversion operator error C2678 in VS2013, works in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-overloading

I have a piece of code that is succesfully compiled in VS2008 and fails to compile in VS2013.

There is a class `Data::CData` which is a variant type implementation. It has a conversion operator overloading:

```
template<class T> T&        GetValue();
template<class T> const T&  GetValue() const;
template<class T> operator T&() { return GetValue<T>(); }
template<class T> operator const T&() const { return GetValue<T>(); }
```

The code that produces an error is

```
Data::CData Val;
Data::PParams Prm = (const Data::PParams&)Val;
```

The error is: error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Data::PParams' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

And this code is successfully compiled by both compilers:

```
Data::CData Val;
Data::PParams Prm = Val.operator const Data::PParams&();
```

What do I do wrong?

Example that reproduces a problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjohnu5v87tyr2c/ConstOverload.zip?dl=0

Comment: For that cast, overload resolution should select `operator T&()` with `T` deduced as `const Data::PParams`. Without knowing the definition of `GetValue` and `Data::PParams` it's hard to say much, but that extra `const` qualifier there could mess things up if you aren't expecting it.

Comment: The old-style cast might not always do what you expect.  Use a static_cast instead and see if it changes the behavior.  But, why not just call `GetValue<>` directly?

Comment: I'm also reminded of a bug (intentional extension) in Visual C++ that allows binding of a const reference in some contexts where it's not allowed.  Maybe that went away in a newer version and the old behavior was relying on that.  In any case, the addition of rvalue references makes such things come out differently; they might have needed to fix minor issues to get the new more complex rules to work right.

Comment: For T.C. Yes, I made the same conclusion. But what is still unclear for me is did VS2008 allow something wrong or VS2013 denies something right? All definitions and implementations are available in attached archive.

Comment: To jdlugosz: I tried a static_cast with the same result. In fact, cast doesn't make sense since I want to achieve transparency for my variant class. Originally it must look like `ContainedType x; CData y = x;` and vice versa. Explicit cast is for demonstration purposes only, to show that my overloaded operator is called in a wrong way. Const modifier leads to an ambiguous situation and i try to figure out is there any rule for disambiguation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a solution!
Instead of two operator overloads I used to

```
template<class T> operator T&() { return GetValue<T>(); }
template<class T> operator const T&() const { return GetValue<T>(); }
```

there should be **three**

```
template<class T> operator T&() { return GetValue<T>(); }
template<class T> operator const T&() { return GetValue<T>(); }
template<class T> operator const T&() const { return GetValue<T>(); }
```

So, in VS2013 we also need a dedicated operator to get const reference from non-const object. If someone find an official document where it is defined, post link here please. Hope this answer will help others.